# Web View in Unity for Windows

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, webview

Trying to solve how to provide an **in-game** Web View in a Windows Unity project. This will be used for payment-processing - Paypal/Braintree/Stripe etc.

The following can be used to open an external web browser from within Unity:

```
Application.OpenURL("http://www.example.com");
```

But this doesn't fit customer requirements as it must be in-app.

All of the ready-built solutions I can find are merely wrappers for native WebView capabilities of iOS and Android, and therefore do not support Windows.

Very interested to hear some inspiration on how to tackle this one!